# Different HC3 standard error estimates when normalising weights for weighted least squares fit using Python statsmodels

Tags: python, standard-error, weighted-regression

When I normalize the weights I use for fitting a line with weighted least squares, the parameters of the fitted line and the 'normal' standard errors stay exactly the same, as I would expect.
The HC3 standard error estimates, however, change completely.

I get the feeling that I am missing something quite important here, but... well, I am missing it...

Here is some test code in Python:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

myData = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], dtype=float)
myIndex = sm.add_constant(range(len(myData)))

myWeights = np.array([100,10,100,10,100,10,100,10], dtype=float)

fit1 = sm.WLS(myData, myIndex, weights=myWeights).fit()

print "Parameters: %s" % fit1.params
print "Normal standard errors: %s" % fit1.bse
print "HC3 estimates: %s" % fit1.HC3_se

# Normalise the weights
myWeights /= myWeights.sum()

fit2 = sm.WLS(myData, myIndex, weights=myWeights).fit()

print "Parameters: %s" % fit2.params
print "Normal standard errors: %s" % fit2.bse
print "HC3 estimates: %s" % fit2.HC3_se
```

Which produces:

```
Parameters: [ 0.9796748   0.49186992]
Normal standard errors: [ 0.09876738  0.02581648]
HC3 estimates: [ 0.00976334  0.00314918]
Parameters: [ 0.9796748   0.49186992]
Normal standard errors: [ 0.09876738  0.02581648]
HC3 estimates: [ 44.54587593   0.75750668]
```

Comment: This looks strange to me. Have you tried with some other data or software? I don't read python but I've tried to reproduce this result in R and cannot do so.

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me post as an answer for some reason, but I cannot reproduce this with current master. What version of statsmodels are you using?

Comment: This is not supported in statsmodels 0.5. `HCCM matrices are only appropriate for OLS` documentation for HCxxx http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browser let's me post an answer now...

What version are you using? I can't reproduce this with current master. Probably best to post these kinds of issues to github in the future.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues

```
Parameters: [ 0.9796748   0.49186992]
Normal standard errors: [ 0.09876738  0.02581648]
HC3 estimates: [ 0.06187963  0.02651504]                                        
Parameters: [ 0.9796748   0.49186992]                                           
Normal standard errors: [ 0.09876738  0.02581648]                               
HC3 estimates: [ 0.06187963  0.02651504]
```

Version

```
[~/]
[3]: sm.version.full_version
[3]: '0.6.0.dev-3396b98'
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I've got version 0.5.0. Seems like quite a serious bug if this is really it. Anyway, thanks again, I'll check!

Comment: Indeed, upgrading to '0.6.0.dev-c65f584' solves it.

Comment: From the docs "HCCM matrices are only appropriate for OLS." Granted, we should've at least raised a warning for use after WLS. We need to update the docs now that they're right for weights.

Comment: Do you mean that HCx estimates actually do not work at all for WLS?
Or just not in statsmodels 0.5.0?
As in: the ones returned for the WLS fit in 0.6.0 do make sense??

Comment: Just in statsmodels 0.5.0. The ones in the development branch should be correct, but I'd double-check yourself until there's an official release. They're almost certainly correct, but we need to do a bit more testing before the next release.

Comment: OK, thanks!

Well, in general, the values do look a lot more like what I'ld expect. Though it does happen that sometimes the HC3 standard error estimates are in fact smaller than the normal standard errors. Which is not, I think, what you would expect. Or is it?

Comment: And not just for the intercept, I mean...